# segmentation error (using gcc in kali)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, casting

I am trying to assign an array to `unsigned` var and then print contains using the var. I am running kali on virtualbox and I keep getting the seg error. I am coping code out of a book and this is how it appears:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()  
{  
    int i;
    char char_array[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
    int int_array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    unsigned int hacky_nonpointer;

    hacky_nonpointer = (unsigned int) char_array;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)  
    {   
        // Iterate through hacky_nonpointer with the sizeof(char).  
        printf("[hacky_nonpointer] points to %p, which contains the char '%c'\n",hacky_nonpointer, *((char *) hacky_nonpointer));  
        hacky_nonpointer = hacky_nonpointer + sizeof(char);  
    }

    hacky_nonpointer = (unsigned int) int_array;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)   
    {    
        // Iterate through hacky_nonpointer with the size_of(int) func.   
        printf("[hacky_nonpointer] points to %p, which contains the integer %d\n",hacky_nonpointer, *((int *) hacky_nonpointer));   
        hacky_nonpointer = hacky_nonpointer + sizeof(int);   
    }   
}
```

Compiler output:

```
root@Brien:~# gcc -g -o ./pointer_types5 pointer_types5.c
pointer_types5.c: In function ‘main’:
pointer_types5.c:12:21: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
pointer_types5.c:17:24: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
pointer_types5.c:24:21: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
pointer_types5.c:29:24: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
```

Runtime output:

```
root@Brien:~# ./pointer_types5
Segmentation fault
root@Brien:~#
```

Comment: Running this through a debugger to determine where in the code the segfault occurs would help you, and failing that, us.

Comment: Is `sizeof(unsigned int) == sizeof(void*)` on your system?

Comment: Please follow up the compiler warnings.

Comment: use `uintptr_t` instead of `unsigned int`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be using a system with 32-bit `int` type and 64-bit pointer types. You'll need to use a large enough type for `hacky_nonpointer` to hold the entire pointer value. `uintptr_t` is provided by `stdint.h` for exactly this purpose.

Comment: When I looked at the byte size of int *, or pointer, I get 8bytes.  The same size is for long int.  If I initiate with long int and cast to long int, I do not get a segmentation fault either.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate that this question has been answered one way.
I happen to be reading the same text that the OP posted code from. The author wanted you to *deliberately* use the unsigned int to illustrate a point (based on 32-bit machine).
An alternative that has worked for me is:
"include stdint.h"
...
uint64_t hacky_nonpointer; // A 64-bit unsigned int

hacky_nonpointer = (uint64_t) char_array;

See full code below.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
int main() {

int i;
char char_array[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
int int_array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};


// unsigned int hacky_nonpointer;   <-- This code does not work on 64-bit machines with 64 bit pointers
uint64_t hacky_nonpointer;
hacky_nonpointer = (uint64_t) char_array;

for(i=0; i < 5; i++) { // Iterate through the char array with the char_pointer.
printf("[hacky_nonpointer] points to %p, which contains the char '%c'\n", hacky_nonpointer, *((char *) hacky_nonpointer));
hacky_nonpointer = hacky_nonpointer + sizeof(char);
}

hacky_nonpointer = (uint64_t) int_array;
for(i=0; i < 5; i++) { // Iterate through the int array with the int_pointer.
printf("[hacky_nonpointer] points to %p, which contains the integer %d\n", hacky_nonpointer, *((int *) hacky_nonpointer));
hacky_nonpointer = hacky_nonpointer + sizeof(int);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have answered this another way.

All I needed to do was check the byte size of a `int *` pointer.  I got 8bytes and so is the `long int`.  If hacky_nonpointer is set to `long int` then it works as expected.  An `int` under my system is 4bytes so I was getting a segmentation fault before anything even printed.  My solution works on my system as expected from the illustration provided by the author without `uint64_t`.

```
int i;
char char_array[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
int int_array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

long int hacky_nonpointer;

hacky_nonpointer = (long int) char_array;

for(i=0; i < 5; i++) { // Iterate through the int array with the int_pointer.
    printf("[hacky_nonpointer] points to %p, which contains the char '%c'\n",
           hacky_nonpointer, *((char *) hacky_nonpointer));
    hacky_nonpointer = hacky_nonpointer + sizeof(char);
}

hacky_nonpointer = (long int) int_array;

for(i=0; i < 5; i++) { // Iterate through the int array with the int_pointer.
    printf("[hacky_nonpointer] points to %p, which contains the integer %d\n",
           hacky_nonpointer, *((int *) hacky_nonpointer));
    hacky_nonpointer = hacky_nonpointer + sizeof(int);
}
```